# How Explain plan can be differents between apps

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

I'm here to expose a quite strange behaviour of a request on Oracle 11g.

here the request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT cabmnt___rfovsnide AS c0 
                FROM   cabmnt 
                WHERE  cabmnt___rfovsnide > '200912_001' 
                       AND 1 = 1 
                       AND ( cabmnt___rforefide = 'TEST' ) 
                       AND cabmnt___rfovsnide IS NOT NULL 
                ORDER  BY c0) 
        WHERE  rownum = 1);
```

i have an index on my column cabmnt___rfovsnide.

Here the problem :

on SQLPLUS : it use a nice plan, with index scan

on SQUIRRELSQL : it use the same nice plan, with index scan

on SQLDEVELLOPER : it use an evil plan with TABLE FULL SCAN ( 100M lines :()

on EntrepriseManager : it use an evil plan with TABLE FULL SCAN ( 100M lines :()

**in my real APP :**  it use an evil plan with TABLE FULL SCAN ( 100M lines :()

With the good plan, the query take 0.001 s.

With the bad one : more than 2 minutes.

Have you any ideas ?

Requested info :

CURSOR_SHARING is EXACT.

I Play all this tests on same database

**GOOD PLAN : (IN SQLPLUS and SQuiRREL**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation                      | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time        |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |            |       |       |     4 (100)|              |
 |   1 |  VIEW                          |            |     1 |    18 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                |            |       |       |            |          |
 |   3 |    VIEW                        |            |     2 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CABMNT     |     2 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
 |*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CABMNT_VSN |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

2 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
4 - filter("CABMNT___RFOREFIDE"='TEST')
5 - access("CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE">'200912_001')
```

**BAD PLAN WITH ALL ROWS:  (In SQLDEVELLOPER, Entreprise manager and my APP**

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Id  | Operation                | Name   | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |        |       |       |       |   140K(100)|             |
 |   1 |  VIEW                    |        |     1 |    18 |       |   140K  (1)| 00:32:43 |
 |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY          |        |       |       |       |            |          |
 |   3 |    VIEW                  |        |    16M|   288M|       |   140K  (1)| 00:32:43 |
 |*  4 |     SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY|        |    16M|   288M|   450M|   140K  (1)| 00:32:43 |
 |*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CABMNT |    16M|   288M|       | 79979   (1)| 00:18:40 |

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

2 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
4 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
5 - filter(("CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE">'200912_001' AND "CABMNT___RFOREFIDE"='TEST'))
```

**BAD PLAN WITH FIRST ROWS: (In SQLDEVELLOPER, Entreprise manager and my APP**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name       | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |            |       |       |       |   360K(100)|          |
|   1 |  VIEW                           |            |     1 |    18 |       |   360K  (1)| 01:24:13 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                 |            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                         |            |    16M|   288M|       |   360K  (1)| 01:24:13 |
|*  4 |     SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY       |            |    16M|   288M|   450M|   360K  (1)| 01:24:13 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CABMNT     |    16M|   288M|       |   300K  (1)| 01:10:10 |
|*  6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CABMNT_VSN |    16M|       |       | 29139   (1)| 00:06:48 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

 2 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
 4 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
 5 - filter("CABMNT___RFOREFIDE"='TEST')
 6 - access("CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE">'200912_001')
```

Index on my column :

```
CREATE INDEX "AXABAS"."CABMNT_VSN" ON "AXABAS"."CABMNT" ("CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE") 

  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
 DEFAULT       CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TB_STRUCTURES_AXABAS_OLD" 
null
```

I created it simply with :

```
CREATE INDEX cabmnt_vsn on cabmnt (cabmnt___rfovsnide);
```

**Table DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE cabmnt
(
  **cabmnt___rforefide varchar(32) NOT NULL, -- Referentiel**
  cabmnt___rteprcide varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  cabmnt___rtestdide varchar(32) NOT NULL, -- Stade
  **cabmnt___rfovsnide varchar(32) NOT NULL, -- Version**
  cabmntlil varchar(100), -- libelle long
  cabmntlic varchar(32), -- libelle court
  cabmnttxt varchar(1500), -- Commentaires
  cabmnt___rfontride varchar(32) NOT NULL, -- Nature
  cabmnt_1_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 1
  cabmnt_2_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 2
  cabmnt_3_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 3
  cabmnt_4_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 4
  cabmnt_5_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 5
  cabmnt_6_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 6
  cabmnt_7_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 7
  cabmnt_8_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 8
  cabmnt_9_rfodstide varchar(32), -- Destination axe 9
  cabmntmnt numeric(25,10) NOT NULL, -- Montant
  cabmntsns varchar(1), -- Sens
  cabmnt___rfodevide varchar(32), -- Devise
  cabmnt___rfotytide varchar(32), -- Type de taux devise
  cabmntdtc timestamp, -- Date du taux
  cabmntmtd numeric(25,10), -- Montant en devise
  cabmnt___rfocteide varchar(32), -- cycle temporel
  cabmntdtd timestamp NOT NULL, -- Date debut
  cabmntdtf timestamp NOT NULL, -- Date fin
  cabmntcsu integer NOT NULL, -- Cle de substitution
  cabmntax1 integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax2 integer DEFAULT 2 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax3 integer DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax4 integer DEFAULT 4 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax5 integer DEFAULT 5 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax6 integer DEFAULT 6 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax7 integer DEFAULT 7 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax8 integer DEFAULT 8 NOT NULL,
  cabmntax9 integer DEFAULT 9 NOT NULL,
  cabmnt_o_cabmntcsu integer, -- Montant d'origine
  cabmnt___cabodvcsu integer, -- OD analytique
  cabmnt___cabliscsu integer, -- Lissage
  **CONSTRAINT cabmnt_pk PRIMARY KEY (cabmntcsu) USING INDEX TABLESPACE tb_index_axabas,**
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_dev FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfodevide)
  REFERENCES rfodev (rfodev___rforefide, rfodevide) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds1 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_1_rfodstide, cabmntax1)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds2 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_2_rfodstide, cabmntax2)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds3 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_3_rfodstide, cabmntax3)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds4 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_4_rfodstide, cabmntax4)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds5 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_5_rfodstide, cabmntax5)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds6 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_6_rfodstide, cabmntax6)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds7 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_7_rfodstide, cabmntax7)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds8 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_8_rfodstide, cabmntax8)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ds9 FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt_9_rfodstide, cabmntax9)
  REFERENCES rfodst (rfodst___rforefide, rfodstide, rfodstaxe) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ntr FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfontride)
  REFERENCES rfontr (rfontr___rforefide, rfontride) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_ref FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide)
  REFERENCES rforef (rforefide) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_std FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rteprcide, cabmnt___rtestdide)
  REFERENCES rtestd (rtestd___rteprcide, rtestdide) --MATCH SIMPLE
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  **CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_vsn FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfovsnide)
  REFERENCES rfovsn (rfovsn___rforefide, rfovsnide) --MATCH SIMPLE**
  ,----ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_tyt FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfotytide)
  REFERENCES rfotyt (rfotyt___rforefide, rfotytide),
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_cte FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfocteide)
  REFERENCES rfocte (rfocte___rforefide, rfocteide) DEFERRABLE,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_vct FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfovsnide, cabmnt___rfocteide)
  REFERENCES rfovsn (rfovsn___rforefide, rfovsnide, rfovsn___rfocteide) DEFERRABLE,
  CONSTRAINT cabmnt_fk_per FOREIGN KEY (cabmnt___rforefide, cabmnt___rfocteide, cabmntdtd)
  REFERENCES rfoper (rfoper___rforefide, rfoper___rfocteide, rfoperdtd) DEFERRABLE
)
```

Comment: What is the value of cursor_sharing ?

Comment: t would be useful to see the different plans -- I assume that if the table is that large and performance is sometimes that good then you have an index on (cabmnt___rforefide,cabmnt___rfovsnide). I'd expect that dynamic sampling would help in getting a good plan due to the presence of two predicates.

Comment: i adding what you both asked

Comment: Does your environment is RAC or single instance?
In a RAC environment you can find yourself having different plain in each node.

Comment: It's a single instance environnement, thanks for all your quick answers :)

Comment: How to format my plans to have nice presentation on my post ? any ideas ?

Comment: Add four spaces in front of each line

Comment: What's the definition for the index CABMNT_VSN?

Comment: Can you get the full output of extracting the plan using DBMS_Xplan.display? It should show filters and access, and whether dynamic sampling was used etc

Comment: The good one is NOT in ALL_ROWS optimizer mode

Comment: it's an error, i tried FIRST ROWS after and i regenarate the plan for you :) Problem is the same with FIRST ROWS and ALL ROWS

Comment: it retry just for beaing sure

Comment: checked, in all case my database is in FIRST_ROWS since i change it for the whole system

Comment: Come to think of it, an index on (CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE, cabmnt___rforefide) would probably be the best thing.

Comment: Was the index added very recently, and the app and SQL Developer queries first run before, and the other two afterwards? Oracle seems to see them as different queries, but to have different plans might suggest something changed between them being parsed?

Comment: We tried this query many time in different order, indeed oracle consider my query 5 environnement i've explained in two queries ( two id), one with the good plan, the other with a bad one.

Comment: i've already tried to flush shared pool

Comment: Just wondering, is it a case of the new feature as in PLSQL optimiser rearranging the code for performance improvement and making a wrong decision ?
Maybe PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL might help?

Comment: i tried your idea, no result but thank you for idea !

Comment: Just in case you missed it, an index on (cabmnt___rfovsnide, cabmnt___rforefide) makes most sense to me.

Comment: there is only one value in the column cabmnt___rforefide (it depends on app configuration, but 99% true), are you sure  it's not a waste of time to create it ? ( I'm ,trying it anyway :) )

Comment: this try give me another plan, but not the one i want... (2.5 seconds query, with fast fullscan on the new index) i update the main question with this try.

Comment: Your statistics must be off. The optimizer chooses a full table scan by default. Only when executed in a first_rows optimizer environment, does it choose the plan with the index range scan. If you want the query to choose this plan without specifying first_rows, you'll need to show us the entire plan including predicate section with "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor)", after the explain plan.

Comment: I've added what you asked, **predicate information**. And indeed they are not the same in the two cases... sql ids are different two. But i execute the same query in both case with COPY-PASTE !!

Comment: i very badly test the first_rown option, i have alter system only, it looks like my running session where not altered so i have now another BAD EXECUTION PLAN... :)

Comment: What happens if you copy-paste the other way, from SQL*Plus to SQL Developer? I'm wondering if it sees it as different SQL because of something as trivial as the difference between spaces and tabs. Not that it would explain much. Do you have a login profile (`login.sql` or `glogin.sql`) or equivalent for SQuirreL SQL that's altering your session in some way that's beneficial? Clutching at straws here, clearly.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do the statements select count(\*) from cabmnt where CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE>'200912_001' AND CABMNT___RFOREFIDE='CHUL'  and  select count(*) from cabmnt where CABMNT___RFOVSNIDE>'20091_001'  give?

Comment: The first one give 17.616.298 lines in 13 seconds.
The second one give 17.616.298 lines in 2.5 seconds.

It's very strange oracle not taking the same index on rfovsn for both request

Answer (score 2):

The execution plan can vary both due to optimizer goal as well as to anomalies in the platform/driver (which I consider a bug, but it has been around a lot).

Please check the settings of the optimizer_goal on session.

Also make sure that you check it identical conditions and with identical data. Value peeking can lead to different execution plans, as well as different statistics and platforms.

> Another cause can be that the Oracle kernel has by default another
>   preferred optimizer_goal for SQL and PL/SQL: with PL/SQL all_rows and
>   with SQL first_rows by default when I recall correctly.

**Some SQL tips:**

1. Do not use () around the çabmnt___rforefide = 'TEST'; they are superfluous.
2. Consider analytical functions instead of relying on an order by within an inline view.
3. Ordering by in an inline is bad coding style (IMHO).
4. Better move the '1=1' behind the 'where' which makes editing easier (but can cause sometimes optimization issues). And put what is now behind the where in an 'and'. Or remove it.

Comment: optimizer_mode is ALL_ROWS in all cases ( just checked)

Comment: i removed 1 = 1 and () that were added by sql generation, but no change, bad plan stay bad and good ones stay good. Data are exactly the same, i play theses five test on the same database.

Comment: optimizer_mode is not ALL_ROWS in your good plan. Look closely at the first line.

Comment: when i post the plan here i was testing the first rows mode in all environnement, but it is not working, since you asked for Predicates i correct my plans with the real one with predicate, any optimizer mode as no inpact !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?:

```
SELECT max(cabmnt___rfovsnide) AS c0 
FROM   cabmnt 
WHERE  cabmnt___rfovsnide > '200912_001' 
AND    cabmnt___rforefide = 'TEST'
AND    cabmnt___rfovsnide IS NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: perhaps it could do the trick, but with min, the main objective of this request is to get the first value of cabmnt___rfovsnide in table cabmnt that is "greater" than '200912_001'. The whol objective is to simulate a quicker "select distinct cabmnt___rfovsnide from cabmnt". Oracle is very slow for this, so i do many time the request i present here and it is a lot quicker... strangely. ( when the index is used...)

Comment: This is capable of using exactly the same index, and represents the same logic. Oracle can perform a scan of the index even if it does not cover all the predicates, probing the table to check whether the conditions are all met.

Comment: you request is very slow... i just try it... 20 seconds. Mine with the good index : 0.01. Index is not used in your query, with SQUIRREL, method wich use the good index on my query...

Comment: if i remove the CABMNT___RFOREFIDE clause in both query, mine and yours, ORACLE is taking the index ALL TIMES on ALL environments. It look like the first step to the solution :) (But i still need this clause)

Comment: Sounds like it would be worth hinting for the index usage you want then

Comment: Well in that case I'd try upping the level of dynamic sampling. The optimiser thinks that the predicate on CABMNT___RFOREFIDE is matched vary rarely -- dynamic sampling would indicate that it is very commonly matched

Comment: in the table this column has is fact one single value, this is why i dont want to put index on. How to up the dynamic sampling value ?

Comment: with dynamic sampling increased to 4 : same problem, to 10 (all statement), same problem. But it was a logic thing to try

Comment: How was computed the stats on this table ?

Comment: The statement by David is identical and can give identical. Can you add the DDL of the table and include whether the columns are nullable?

Comment: dbms_stats.gather_table_stats => FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE AUT
   cascade=>TRUE
   Block_sample=> TRUE
   degree=>  4 
                        no_invalidate => true
                        estimate_percent=> 5

Comment: Why no_invalidate => true? I think you want false.

Comment: Indeed, it's a mistake, thanks, but no impact on this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I try an auto-answer :)

My final objective was to request all distinct value of rfovsnide in cabmnt, the best method i found was to play the query i present to you as many times as it can find another version ( changing the > condition every time), but oracle decided to not taking indexes and be very slox

I find another query giving the same result and taking my indexes in every scenario :

```
select rfovsnide from rfovsn 
where rfovsn___rforefide = 'TEST' 
and exists( 
         select 1 from cabmnt where cabmnt___rfovsnide = rfovsnide)
```

I inverted the logic, puting the filter on the lighter table and checking on id only on my ultra huge table and the plan is perfect... index on both table, instant query...

**EDIT**

**It's an alternative but not really a response to the real problem : WHY DONT ORACLE take this my nice INDEX !!!**

Comment: Where di this table "rfovsn" come from? I've got no idea how this is the same logic as the other query.

Comment: i didnt give the DDL for **rfovsn** but as described on cabmnt ddl it **is another table pointed by cabmnt**. I want to find all value of rfovsn that are present in cabmnt in the quickest way

Comment: If you had explained originally that, "I want to find all value of rfovsn that are present in cabmnt in the quickest way" then someone could have given you *exactly that SQL*. Next time, please explain what problem you're really trying to solve, because even now the value of your original query in helping you meet that goal completely eludes me.

Comment: Indeed, i don't explain it all, but the reason Oracle doesn't taking the same plan for same query stay the real question :)